# Binding obserable collection to combobox - i did research

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have red several threads about this problem and most of them provides one answer. Yet, it does not work for me. Combobox still dont want to show me data.

I want to bind ObservableCollection to combobox.

DropDownElement is simply

```
 class DropDownElement
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }


    public DropDownElement() { }
    public DropDownElement(string key, string value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbStage" 
                  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=v_stage}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                  SelectedValuePath="Key"
                  />
```

ViewModel:

```
(...) 
class PacksViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
      public ObservableCollection<DropDownElement> v_stage = new ObservableCollection<DropDownElement>();
 (..)
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        PacksViewModel dc = new PacksViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();             
            dc.stagesFill(); // method that fills v_stage with data from DB
            this.DataContext = dc;
        }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Previously i was working like that and it worked but now i want to do it correct way

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cbStage.DataContext = dc.stagesFill(); // in that case method fills collection with data and returns v_stage

    }

<ComboBox Name="cbStage" 
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                      SelectedValuePath="Key"
                      />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v_stage` must be a dependency property or a property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: More important (and sufficient here), it must by a public property, not a field.

Comment: Yes , definitely it must be a property at least ;-)